# Should it be classified as intrinsic or extrinsic variable star if the brightness of the star changes due to the expansion of the universe?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, astronomy, stars

The [Wikipedia article on Variable stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_star) says the following:

> Variable stars may be either intrinsic or extrinsic.

> Intrinsic variable stars: stars where the variability is being caused by changes in the physical properties of the stars themselves. This category can be divided into three subgroups.
> $\Large\cdot$ Pulsating variables, stars whose radius alternately expands and contracts as part of their natural evolutionary ageing processes.
> $\Large\cdot$Eruptive variables, stars who experience eruptions on their surfaces like flares or mass ejections.
> $\Large\cdot$Cataclysmic or explosive variables, stars that undergo a cataclysmic change in their properties like novae and supernovae.

> Extrinsic variable stars: stars where the variability is caused by external properties like rotation or eclipses. There are two main subgroups.
> $\Large\cdot$ Eclipsing binaries, double stars where, as seen from Earth's vantage point the stars occasionally eclipse one another as they orbit.
> $\Large\cdot$ Rotating variables, stars whose variability is caused by phenomena related to their rotation. Examples are stars with extreme "sunspots" which affect the apparent brightness or stars that have fast rotation speeds causing them to become ellipsoidal in shape.

Here I'm not fully sure if it should be classified as intrinsic variable or extrinsic variable star if change in the brightness of a star is due to expansion of the universe.

I would say it's not intrinsic since it's not due to change in the physical properties of the star. But from the definition of the extrinsic variable stars, it seems like this should be caused by some physical objects (rather than spacetime itself) like binaries or star's own rotation.

Which category does this hypothetical star belong to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither, a star with unchanging intrinsic brightness and nothing external crossing our view of it that only becomes dimmer to us because of increasing distance is not a variable star. This is why, as you seem to say, it does not really fit either category. It will become dimmer and more redshifted as we see it accelerate away from us, due to the expansion of space, until it passes the Hubble radius where we will no longer be able to receive the light it emits.